# Creating an application in Intuit developer website account

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I work in quick books onlineV3. Registered my application in the developer.intuit account.

Created an application by entering my host name, application URL, Disconnect Landing URL,
Manage Users URL, OpenID URl.

Used the App Tokens, consumer key and consumer secret keys  in my application.

Above works fine.

I want to create one more application like the above. Can i use the same URL ?
If used, will there be any problem when using the before application ?
If not, what things i got to take care of ?

Looking forward your earliest reply,
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> Can i use the same URL ? If used, will there be any problem when using the before application ? If not, what things i got to take care of ?

You could technically use the same URL... but how are you going to tell which app is which if it's the same URL?

You probably want to use a different URL (even if it's just a query string to let you tell the difference between the two apps). Otherwise you won't be able to tell which connection is for which app.

Make sure to check out the [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) too if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. Can i remove my first application created in developer account and use that application URL for the new application ? Will the new application work fine ?  But, once again if i use the application URL for the first application, it will not work { Because apptoken, consumer key, appkey will be generated with new pairs } Is my understanding correct ? Looking forward your earliest reply, Thanks ..

Comment: Bottom line here: If you have two applications, you should have two URLs. If you have one application, you'll have one URL. Don't make things more complicated than they need to be unless you can explain a REALLY good reason to do so. Extra applications and URLs don't cost anything, so there's no reason not to do this.